# Less.css Code Formatting

Tags: less, visual-studio-code, sublimetext, code-formatting

I want to code format my Less stylesheets similar to how Bootstrap does it - by column.  I don't know if I'm languaging it right, so I've included a screenshot of what I'm looking for:

[image: Less Formatting Screenshot]

Currently I use either Sublime Text or Visual Studio Code, or, I guess Vim sometimes, but I do most coding in the first two.  I can do this manually, but it's a pain in the *ss.

I've also experimented with Sublime plugin [AlignTab](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/AlignTab), but I didn't get anywhere.

I've looked quite a bit for how to do this, but I concede that it's possible I'm missing something obvious.  I'm tempted to email Bootstrap developers, and ask how they do it.  Can't be too hard, can it?

Answer (score 1):

There are several extensions [in the marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/search?term=align&target=VSCode&sortBy=Relevance) that aim to solve this issue. I just installed Align, the most popular one, and then copied the first less code I could find from http://lesscss.org/

```
@base: #f938ab;

.box-shadow(@style, @c) when (iscolor(@c)) {
  -webkit-box-shadow: @style @c;
  box-shadow:         @style @c;
}
.box-shadow(@style, @alpha: 50%) when (isnumber(@alpha)) {
  .box-shadow(@style, rgba(0, 0, 0, @alpha));
}
.box {
  color: saturate(@base, 5%);
  border-color: lighten(@base, 30%);
  div { .box-shadow(0 0 5px, 30%) }
}
```

I then selected the code and used the align command and got this:

[image]

Some of the other extensions might not require you to select the text first, or might format differently, so don't be afraid to try them out.

If you're asking if there is a built-in way to do this, though, not to my knowledge.